# How to get the string value from a char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory, char, copy

I have a `char array` in `C`

```
#define BUFSIZE 2048
unsigned char buf[BUFSIZE];

char request[10];
strcat(request "GET key01");
request[10] = '\0';

buf = request;
```

The request is coming from a the network with a `client-server socket` simulation, but I did not include that here to keep it simple.

Anyways, I have to tokenize the `buf` string, but also keep an untokenized copy. I tried this:

```
char* buf_for_token = buf;
printf("What is the buf before tokenization? %s\n", buf);

const char s[2] = " ";
char *token;
token = strtok(buf_for_token, s);
token = strtok(NULL, s);

printf("What is the buf after tokenization? %s\n", buf);
```

My output is:

```
What is the buf before tokenization? GET key01
What is the buf after tokenization? GET
```

I would instead like:

```
What is the buf before tokenization? GET key01
What is the buf after tokenization? GET key01
```

How can I get the value of a string from a char array and save a copy that I can manipulate without affecting the original value?

Comment: What is `strcat(request "GET key01");` supposed to do? It's not even valid syntax. Did you mean `strcpy(request, "GET key01");`?

Comment: The simple answer is to make a copy of the buffer with `strcpy`, and tokenize the copy.

Comment: token = strtok(buf_for_token, s);
printf("What is the buf after tokenization? %s\n", buf);
token = strtok(NULL, s);

Comment: `strcat(request "GET key01");` concatenates a string to uninitialized memory.

Comment: @Barmar:  I'm assuming he just made a typo posting the code and left out the comma.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I assumed so as well, but the use of `strcat` rather than `strcpy` shows that he's more confused than that.

Comment: Why not just use `char request[10] = "GET key01";` to initialize it?

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm not very strong with C memory management. I will accept one of the answers when I get home #javaGuy

Comment: I'm not sure why I get down voted though. Am I doing something that is discouraged by the community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the C `<string.h>` function:

```
strcpy(const char *dest, const char *src);
```

Which will copy from src until '\0' char, into dest, and include the '\0' char.

**OR**

use:

```
strcat(const char *dest, const char *src);
```

Which will append to the end of the already existent string, starting at null terminate '\0' of dest, adding all chars until and including '\0'.

**OR**

use:

```
strncpy(const char *dest, const char *src, int size);
```

Which wil copy n chars from char *src into char *dest.

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` is destructive; it will modify the contents of your buffer as you tokenize it by overwriting the delimiters with a zero byte. If you need to preserve the original buffer contents, then you will either need to copy to another buffer and tokenize that second buffer, or you will need to use something besides `strtok` (which is often the right answer anyway).

Look at functions like `strchr` or `strpbrk`.  You'll need to figure out how to extract and save the individual tokens to another buffer, but that's not that hard.